# What's the keyEvent for the arrow down button on the keyboard?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I would like to clear the focus of the edit text when my keyboard is closed but unfortunately there is a key on the keyboard of which I don't know the [keyEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html). Can somebody clarify please?

[Here's the reference for the KeyEvent class.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

[image]

EDIT 1:
This is my code:

```
holder.editText.setOnEditorActionListener { v, actionId, event ->

                if(actionId == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL || actionId == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                    val imm = v.context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0)
                    v.clearFocus()
                    true
                } else {
                    false
                }
            }
```

Comment: You will not find it in keyEvents because its not part of keyboard, but system provided navigation.

Comment: @Chris8447 I will suggest you to use getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(){ }

Comment: @Chris8447 Call this method for your view and handle the action

Comment: if you are only concerned about particular keyEvent you may try onBackPressed().. however the solution by @Venky is a better choice.

Comment: Thanks for your proposals. Please see my edit. How would a GlobalLayoutListener help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same as for the back key ([KEYCODE_BACK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_BACK)), it's behaviour does actually not change.

Some device manufacturers indeed change the icon to make it more clear what it does when the keyboard is open, but it is still the same back button key press and action.

Comment: Implementing your answer doesn't change the outcome unfortunately. See my update to the question.

Comment: `KEYCODE_BACK` is not an editor action event, you will not receive it via that listener. The easiest would be overriding onBackPressed on the activity, or you could add a View.OnKeyListener, on any of your view in the activity.

Comment: Implementing onBackPressed is not firing for the scenario that the keyboard is hiding. It is firing when the activity is actually closing though. I guess I have to find another solution.

Comment: Did you try the onKeyListener?